# Count number of files in a FTP folder

Tags: matlab, ftp, ftp-client

I use this code to see existed files in a specific folder from FTP :

```
ftp_client = ftp('IP','Username','Password');
aa = dir(ftp_client,'First_folder/Second_folder');
```

I can see file names with these codes :

```
aa(1,1).name
aa(2,1).name
aa(3,1).name
```

1. How can I see all files names in a cell aray in this specific folder? Is there any command for it?
2. How can I count number of existed files in this folder?
3. How can I count number of existed files in this folder with a specific format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A simple way is to collect the values into the cell array by using curly brackets: `filenames = {aa.name};`
2. The simplest method would be `length(aa);` or `length(filenames);`
3. A couple ways. You can either refine your [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) call, `aa = dir(ftp_client,'First_folder/Second_folder/*.jpeg')` for example, or use your own filter ([`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) is one option) on your filenames to return the indices of what you want.

As a general aside, if you're utilizing this program on different operating systems, I would recommend utilizing [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) (or [`filesep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filesep.html) at the very least) to build your full pathnames to ensure the right separator is used. Though I didn't do it in my example above...